# XCode 4.2 Version Inspector Hides Storyboard

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard

I'm not sure if anyone else is having the problem...but when I click the Version Editor button in XCode...my Storyboard switches to XML view and I can't figure out how to get the Visual editor back.

Can anyone help?  I'm really hoping this is just a result of late night coding sleepiness...thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: I just had the exact same problem.  I'm sure Apple will be fixing this one soon.

Comment: I've written up a bug report to track your problem.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Right click on the storyboard file -> Open As -> iOS Storyboard

Comment: This is the easiest solution.

Comment: Thanks. Took me a month to spot it.

Comment: Added full instructions here: http://www.stuarticus.com/2011/11/08/xcode-storyboard-how-to-get-the-storyboard-view-back/

Comment: wow. Thanks for this answer. I spent ten minutes cursing at Apple.

Comment: In Xcode 6.2 if you are in source view, "Open As" has no available options.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to do that is to go to the File menu and close the file.  I had to close all open storyboards then select them again.

Comment: This is really a mess...I can't believe this is intentional, haha.  I'll dig for more answers and report back...this just can't be the answer, otherwise the "feature" of the version editor is nearly useless because of the hassle it creates

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue (now the year is 2014) and the fix was clicking the icon on the top right for 'Show the Standard Editor' and you'll get your storyboard back. Here's a hint for the youngbloods, it's the one to the right of the bowtie on the tux.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the reference to `MainStoryBoard.storyboard` (Right-click → Delete → Remove Reference Only), and drag it back into the project via Finder.

Comment: hmm, so this sounds like a bug, right?  That can't be the "official" way...right?  Anyway, thanks for responding tomblah

Comment: yeah, it's a hack :), @Dave Ferguson's answer is better

Comment: This may work, but it's not a good idea. Just do it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have open version control?
press command + return