# Why can I only view Storyboard's source and not Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, ios5, storyboard, uistoryboard

I was using Xcode and making changes to my storyboard... no problem.  Now, I get the source code for the storyboard but not the storyboard images!

When I right click on the storyboard file, I don't see "Interface Builder - IOS Storyboard" as an option.

Anyone have this happen to them?

Answer (score 14):

see: [XCode 4.2 Version Inspector Hides Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7911658/1445313)

> When I right click on the storyboard file, I don't see "Interface
>   Builder - IOS Storyboard" as an option.

*Open As* > *InterfaceBuilder - IOS Storyboard*

probably you opened the file as source code...

Comment: if in open as there is no option: you might be version editor mode, and then the storyboard is always in code mode. In this case, just switch in back to the standard editor

Comment: The option to `Open As > Interface Builder - iOS Storyboard` isn't always present.

Answer (score 3):

What's always worked for me when `Open As -> Interface Builder - iOS Storyboard` isn't an option is to:

1. Close Xcode
2. Reopen

Sometimes this happens when you have:

- Just resolved a merge conflict
- Split into diff view to compare previous and current commits

Answer (score -1):

[Click this icon in the top right of the Xcode window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1WuZ.png)